# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, jquery

This error coming up when i generating thumbnail using canvas for .mpg format.

It's working for mp4, mov and some other formats.
Can anyone help me out on this like what should i do which works for all type of formats?

```
function generateThumbnail(file){
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var video_obj = null;
    var tempFile = file;
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      var timeupdate = function() {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
          video.pause();
        }
      };
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
          video_obj = this;
      }, false);
      
      var snapImage = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var image = canvas.toDataURL();
      var success = image.length > 100000;
      if (success) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
      return success;
      };
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.src = url;
      // Load video in Safari / IE11
      video.muted = true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.play();
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share some of your code if you want help. It's almost impossible to help you without looking through the code you have already written.

Comment: Hi Enjiar. I have attached the code in question itself which i am using to generate thumbnail of any uploading video.